# Why local strings declared into the main function is part of Rodata segment memory?

Tags: c, memory, assembly, reverse

After disassembling the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char HELLO1[] = "Howdy";

int main(){
char hello2[6]="hello\0";
printf("%s",string);
}
```

I can see that the string **HELLO1** is declared into the **.RODATA** segment that is understandable as constant variables are declared into this segment.

However, **hello2** is also declared into the **.RODATA** segment. But local variables are declared into the **Stack** directly right?

Can you explain me why this string is declared into this segment ?

Comment: Answer depends on complier/platform used - which are both missing.

Comment: Duke, what is the compilation flag you are using? The `hello2` is not created on the stack as per @NulledPointer comment below however; they could have emitted a stacked string. I've noticed that `clang` will also do this with aggregate data types on occasion as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C programs often use memcpy and memset internally to build the contents of the stack at runtime.  Although it's platform dependent, it's common for code like yours to expand to something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char HELLO1[] = "Howdy";

int main(){
    // hidden
    static const char *__temporary_main_hello2 = "hello\0";
    char hello2[6];
    // hidden
    memcpy(hello2, __temporary_main_hello2, sizeof(hello2));
    printf("%s",string);
}
```

You can see now why hello is also in .rodata.  The original data for the string comes from a static in .rodata, but the storage for the array hello2 is on the stack.  The compiler needs a way to populate hello2 when main is called.  If the platform has a convenient way to represent data in immediates, it might be done that way, but it's generally more convenient to use the well optimized memcpy for this.

Comment: It's more common on x86 for initializer data to go into immediate constants in the instruction stream, rather than being copied from static data. See my comment on the other answer.  But maybe the OP is compiling for ARM?  (Where it takes at least three instructions to store 32 bits of literal data to memory.)  Godbolt has ARM compilers, too: and indeed the initializer is copied from `.LC0` (after spending two instruction to get the address of .LC0 into a register).  https://godbolt.org/g/b7RbW0

Comment: Sorry for my late comment. I'm using GCC for x86. Can you tell why your answer and NulledPointer's are not the same ? Is your answer an explanation of the the static storage implementation by GCC (by using memcpy to build the contents of the stack at runtime)?

Comment: Both answers come to the same conclusion but I was thinking that it's easier to see what's happening practically with a concrete example.

Comment: Can you explain me then why your static const char *__temporary_main_hello2 variable is declared inside the main function and he still in data segment ? Normally, all local variables are stored in stack segment. Otherwise, thanks. Both answers served me to understand. I choose you as the best answer for the concrete example.

Comment: Look up "static storage duration" as below.  Static locals and static members have static storage duration, which for PoD informally means that their lifetime is the lifetime of the whole program.  So a static local is effectively a global variable that's only visible in one lexical scope, just as a static member is effectively a global that's namespaced to its owner class.

Answer (score 4):

[String literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) exists for the lifetime of the program

> String literals have [static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), and thus exist in memory
>   for the life of the program.

[Static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

> The storage for the object is allocated when the program begins and
>   deallocated when the program ends. Only one instance of the object
>   exists. All objects declared at namespace scope (including global
>   namespace) have this storage duration, plus those declared with static
>   or extern.

So `gcc` implement `static storage` in `.RODATA` in `ELF` binary

To elaborate further...

```
char a[] = "Hello world A";
char* p  = "Hello world P";
```

For both `a` and `p`, their string literals have static storage duration (that means they are both stored in `.RODATA`) with difference being that for `a` the string literal is copied in this stack variable while `p` just points to `.RODATA` memory. That is why you can modify `a` but not `p`

NOTE: Know that references above are from `c++` syntax but the reason for `c` is same

Comment: This is nice answer, however `char hello2[6]="hello\0";` does not constitute `"hello\0"` as _string literal_. The `"hello\0"` initializer serves as synctatic sugar for `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` _array initializer_.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski updated answer for your confusion.

Comment: C11 6.7.9/p14: `An array of character type may be initialized by a **character string literal** or UTF−8 string
literal, optionally enclosed in braces.`. I also checked `char hello2[6]= "hel" "lo\0";`, which is valid construct and proves your point.

Comment: Using a literal as an array initializer means that it doesn't have to exist as a string anywhere; @GrzegorzSzpetkowski is right.  It will often end up as immediate data for store instructions.  (So it's written directly from the instructions to the stack, not copied from read-only static data to the non-const array.)  See [a demonstration on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/uTL4sg)